Why does GPT4All not strictly follow the JSON format specified in the prompt and add extra text?
I’m using GPT4All in a Python script to classify emails by category, priority, and response requirement. Despite a clear prompt specifying a strict JSON format and instructions to exclude additional text, the LLM frequently outputs invalid JSON, includes comments or explanations, and sometimes adds unwanted placeholders like  or " ". This behavior makes it difficult to process the LLM’s output programmatically.
I used the following MODEL_SETTINGS to ensure the LLM generates deterministic and focused outputs:
MODEL_SETTINGS = {
    "temp": 0.0,  # Ensures deterministic outputs
    "top_p": 0.5,  # Focuses on the highest probability tokens
    "top_k": 1,  # Chooses the top token every time
    "repeat_penalty": 2.5,  # Penalizes repetitive sequences
}

prompt = (
    f"<user>\n"
    f"You are an AI system that only outputs JSON objects. Your task is to classify the following email into a predefined JSON format.\n\n"
    f"Email details:\n"
    f"Subject: \"{subject}\"\n"
    f"Sender: \"{sender}\"\n\n"
    f"### Output Format\n"
    f"Respond only in this JSON format:\n"
    f"{{\n"
    f"    \"Category\": \"<Work, School, or Shopping>\",\n"
    f"    \"Priority\": \"<Important or Normal>\",\n"
    f"    \"RequiresResponse\": \"<Yes or No>\"\n"
    f"}}\n\n"
    f"### Example Response\n"
    f"{{\n"
    f"   \"Category\": \"Work\",\n"
    f"   \"Priority\": \"Normal\",\n"
    f"   \"RequiresResponse\": \"No\"\n"
    f"}}\n\n"
    f"### Important Instructions\n"
    f"1. Output *only* a single JSON object in the exact format provided above.\n"
    f"2. *Do not include any additional text, comments, explanations, or blank lines.*\n"
    f"3. Your response *must* be a valid JSON object with proper capitalization, syntax (double quotes, etc.), and no trailing commas.\n"
    f"4. If you cannot classify the email, leave the values blank (e.g., \"Category\": \"\") but maintain the JSON structure.\n\n"
    f"Now classify the email:\n"
    f"%1<end>\n"
    f"<assistant>\n"
    f"%2<end>\n"
)

I expected the LLM to output a valid JSON object strictly adhering to the provided format, such as:
{
    "Category": "Work",
    "Priority": "Normal",
    "RequiresResponse": "No"
 }

What actually happened?
The LLM often outputs responses with issues like:

Extra text, explanations, or comments.
Invalid JSON structure with missing quotes or keys.
Unnecessary placeholders such as <br/>, &nbsp;, or %1<end>.


There's no guarantee that the output of a LLM is even based in reality. There shouldn't really be an expectation for it to accurately adhere to strict format specifications.

but to i need to modify something in the prompt or model setting?

No, you need to stop expecting LLMs to do something meaningful. You can't restrict their outpit format. You can't ensure consistent output format or quality. You can't prevent them from inventing meaningless rubbish and pretending it's true with a very confident language. It's just not a thing you can reasonably program.

Yes, this is not a programming problem, and stop expecting LLMs to produce desirable outputs, these are just plain hallucinations
